# Elasticsearch for indexing multiple databases

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch and I have tried to see if a answer to this questions exists already but could not find it.  My question is, I have data in multiple datastores (Hadoop, cassandra, Oracle and maybe more in the future).  I want to use Elasticsearch to index all of these datastores and create a "master index".  Is this possible?  Also would the processing of indexing "move" all my data into EC?

Comment: There may be a way to use Kafka as a messaging system between all your datastores. All messages go to elasticsearch (through logstash), but only the necessary ones go to the individual datastores

Comment: The data is already stored in the datastores.  I want to "index" existing data that is present in the datastores

Comment: Well, you'd need a way to pull the data into elasticsearch for each datastore. Logstash is the preferred way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hadoop data you can go for **ES-Hadoop-Connector**. Create an index with mappings before dumping data into Elastic Search and then use the same index for holding your data.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost:9200");
    conf.set("es.resource.write", "Index_Name/Document_Type");
```

Similarly for all the remaining sources use the same index as sink. for each source change the corresponding **Document_Type** with same index name. so that it will become master index of you entire data.

Comment: so basically I would save some metadata in the document object about the datasource so I would know the origin of each document?

Comment: exactly...you have to prepare metadata about the data source [called as mappings in elastic search] + index settings [contains analyzers and tokenizers] before loading into the destination